# Find Adjacent only knowing Angle and Opposite

Tags: trigonometry

Can you find the length of the adjacent side of a right triangle only knowing the length of the opposite side and the angle?

If so how do you calculate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  $$\tan(\theta)=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}$$So$$\text{adjacent}=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\tan(\theta)}$$